Java model class does not creates a table in PostgreSQL database
The program runs well. Errors do not occur, but the Student class does not create a table in the database, even though i provided all of the required annotations and connected PostgereSQL correctly.
I was following this guide (1:11:25-1:16:51): https://youtu.be/fL5NDw0rDOI?t=4285&si=kr1T0h7YQkr0h47T
And here is the OG guide's git: https://github.com/Asher404QQ/spring_boot_2023/blob/main/pom.xml
Note: i am using Eclipse, so maybe the issue is within my IDE
package ru.kors.springstudents.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Transient
    private int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return Period.between(dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
}

UDP: i've changed .yaml file, so now it looks like this
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SpringStudent101
    username: postgres
    password: 4221
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true

my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>ru.kors</groupId>
    <artifactId>springstudents</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springstudents</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Tables folder should contain tables of Student class
enter image description here

Is this a typo in your config file? properies:hibernate: Also if you are seeing any error, always post the stacktrace to your question.

Also if you your application.yaml is like that you need to fix it. Indentation is sensitive important to this type of file https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#61-indentation-spaces

Another typo at datasourse. Should be datasource

Here is the solution shown below
In your application.yaml file, there's a typo in datasourse (it should be datasource
Another problem is related with prefix of database connection url. I've updated the URL prefix from jdbs to jdbc. The correct prefix is jdbc:postgresql://
Here is the corrected version of application.yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SpringStudent101
    username: postgres
    password: 4221
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true


thank you for your feedback! i've updated the .yaml file, as you said, but it did not solved the tables problem. Perhaps the issue is with my Eclipse ide...
